# titles next to lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

The feature list for the new version of gnuplot states that "plot title can be placed next to the plot line in the graph proper."  This is something I would like to be able to do automatically, but I can't find mention of how to do this in the documentation (probably because it hasn't been written yet).  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I assume this is in the CVS version (4.7) currently?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the command line documentation, I assume the pdf hasn't been updated yet.  Here's the text:

```
If you want the title of a plotted line to be placed immediately before or
after that line in the graph itself, use `at {beginning|end}`.  This option
may be useful when plotting `with lines` but makes little sense for some
other plot styles.
```

Comment: Where did you find it?  `help key`?