# gnuplot print legend directly next to individual graphs

Tags: gnuplot

I want to project a 3D plot into a 2D plot. Assuming f(x,y) describes my 3D plot, I want to treat y as a parameter and simultaneously plot f(x,0), f(x,2), f(x,4), etc. in one 2D plot. Instead of going for different line/point styles and colors with a legend in a corner, I'd like to make each plot in the same style and place a label next to each individual line.

Is this even possible in gnuplot or would I have to fall back on something more complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I had a similar question recently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409068/titles-next-to-lines-in-gnuplot)  There is an option in the development version of gnuplot (4.7.0) that does this.  You can change the position of line titles to be at the end/beginning of the line itself.  If your plot looks like I imagine (sort of a contour plot) this may be what you want:

```
plot f(x,y) title 'f(x,y)' at end
```

Otherwise you may have to specify the labels and their positions manually:

```
help set label
```

for more info.

Comment: Ahh, I thought I had gone through enough old questions. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you were able to use my information, please mark the answer as accepted so others know it helped.