# Place key labels next to line ends

Tags: gnuplot

I have many lines on my plot for different values of one parameter, varying from 2 to 23. It's rather inconvenient and hard-to read to invent different linestyles and place them in a legend.

Instead, I want to label lines just next to their endings, so that it's obvious what line is for what parameter number and what the parameter growth direction is. All the lines then could be drawn just as solid black lines and printed black&white without any readability penalty.

Is it possible in gnuplot? Any version can be used, it does not matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gnuplot print legend directly next to individual graphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808910/gnuplot-print-legend-directly-next-to-individual-graphs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in the [cvs version (4.7.0)](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/development/index.html) of gnuplot using the command

```
plot file title 'my beautiful data' at end
```

It may help to adjust the margins afterward with

```
set rmargin XX
```

since the labels will be to the right of the plot area and may go off the edge of the image.  (gnuplot doesn't have very smart label placement/margin adjustment yet.)

Also see my similar question/answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409068/titles-next-to-lines-in-gnuplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808910/gnuplot-print-legend-directly-next-to-individual-graphs/12809441#12809441).

Comment: Thank you!

…Arr, how did I miss it in the search. Must be the lack of my English, didn't get how to ask my question in the words that would produce a result.